# Use Branch for SKAdNetwork, but the Facebook SDK for Aggregated Event Measurement

Tags: facebook, ads, branch.io, skadnetwork

We are wanting to use Branch for ad attribution - particularly for `SKAdNetwork` as per Branch's recommendation here - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/branchskadnetwork-integration-instructions#app-option-1-use-the-branch-sdk-to-manage-skadnetwork

At the same time, we'd like to use Facebook's AEM (Aggregated Event Measurement).

So Question 1: can Branch handle AEM? I can only find one reference in Branch's documentation to AEM (here: https://help.branch.io/faq/docs/will-branch-support-pcm-or-aem) and (unless I'm misunderstanding) it seems out of date (in the sense that it only references AEM as an app-to-web technology, when Facebook themselves describe it as web-to-app or app-to-app).

If the answer to Question 1 is no, Question 2 is: If I install the Facebook SDK, will that take over the `SKAdNetwork` implementation, or will it work nicely side-by-side with Branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve heard back from the Branch team separately and they’ve told me that:

1. Branch does NOT automatically support Facebook AEM, and that the Facebook SDK must be installed and
2. The Facebook SDK will work fine side-by-side with Branch.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the answers I can provide so far.

Q1: Yes. Facebook's Aggregated Event Measurement framework is designed to provide web-to-web and app-to-web / app-to-app measurement.

We do not need to answer Question 2.